# Make a while for elements with js and foreach

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I have a json object (returned by server) and I want to make a while or a forEach to show products of a cart.
My object's name is response2 and it cantains the products of cart.
I want to make a while where to show into a table the products like this(just idea):

```
<div>
<p>${response2.product}</p>
<p>${response2.price}</p>
</div>
```

Sorry for bad english and low programming experience!
Thanks!

This is how looks like the object:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":46,
      "email":"rr",
      "product":"Tort Oreo",
      "description":"Detalii: (ex: textul de pe tort, unde sa fie plasate figurinele si in ce numar)",
      "figurina":"",
      "img_tort":"nu exista",
      "price":"299"
   },
   {  
      "id":47,
      "email":"rr",
      "product":"Pizza Nevada",
      "description":"Personalizare pizza",
      "figurina":"",
      "img_tort":"",
      "price":"25"
   },
   {  
      "id":48,
      "email":"rr",
      "product":"Pizza Nevada22",
      "description":"Personalizare pizza",
      "figurina":"",
      "img_tort":"",
      "price":"29"
   }
]
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with the example server response? How does `response2` object looks like?

Comment: I edited my q. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON `response2` is an array of objects.

You need to reference the array index, then you can call / access the object element.

```js
var response2 = [  
   {  
      "id":46,
      "email":"rr",
      "product":"Tort Oreo",
      "description":"Detalii: (ex: textul de pe tort, unde sa fie plasate figurinele si in ce numar)",
      "figurina":"",
      "img_tort":"nu exista",
      "price":"299"
   },
   {  
      "id":47,
      "email":"rr",
      "product":"Pizza Nevada",
      "description":"Personalizare pizza",
      "figurina":"",
      "img_tort":"",
      "price":"25"
   },
   {  
      "id":48,
      "email":"rr",
      "product":"Pizza Nevada22",
      "description":"Personalizare pizza",
      "figurina":"",
      "img_tort":"",
      "price":"29"
   }
];

window.onload = function() {
  var i, max = response2.length;
  for(i=0;i<max;i++) {
    console.log("product:["+ response2[i].product +"], price:["+ response2[i].price +"]");
  }
}
```

Comment: the code works but only when i assign in js the object. But in my code, response 2 is the JSOM.stringify from a post request. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: can you help me with parsing the array of objects to js? I think that should resolve my problem

Comment: i fixed that. Thanks

Comment: @PavelProdan : Sorry, was away for a bit, glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `div` with ID `cart` and appending rows as `div > p`. You can do it like so:

```js
const response2 = [  
   {  
      "id":46,
      "email":"rr",
      "product":"Tort Oreo",
      "description":"Detalii: (ex: textul de pe tort, unde sa fie plasate figurinele si in ce numar)",
      "figurina":"",
      "img_tort":"nu exista",
      "price":"299"
   },
   {  
      "id":47,
      "email":"rr",
      "product":"Pizza Nevada",
      "description":"Personalizare pizza",
      "figurina":"",
      "img_tort":"",
      "price":"25"
   },
   {  
      "id":48,
      "email":"rr",
      "product":"Pizza Nevada22",
      "description":"Personalizare pizza",
      "figurina":"",
      "img_tort":"",
      "price":"29"
   }
]

const cart = document.getElementById('cart');

response2.forEach(function (row) {

    const div = document.createElement('div');

    for (let key in row) {
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerText = key + ': ' + row[key];

        div.appendChild(p);
    }

    cart.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="cart"></div>
```

Which iterates over all entries in the `response2` object, then iterates over all keys in the product and appends `<p>`s to the current `<div>` row. After that current row is appended to the `cart`. All repeated for all products and all keys in a product

Comment: i got this error: order:234 Uncaught TypeError: response2.forEach is not a function
    at Object.success (order:234)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Try now, I fixed it

Comment: Oh and don't forget to parse your `response2` once you get it from the server because it may be a string